# ruby: Is it better to pass the numeric id of an active record object, or the object itself?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

My application has long suffered from memory leaks. It's work is mostly long running sidekiq work.

Today I'm adding a method, and I'm wondering what's best way to do it, considering memory efficiency is the #1 priority:

```
# option 1
def func1(product_id)
  product = Product.find(product_id)
  # do something with product
end

# option 2
def func1(product)
  # do something with product
end
```

Which one is best? option 1 passed only integer, and the method does an active record find() call to work the object.

Option 2 gets the object itself, so the method doesn't have to
find() the object.

The method runs several million times per day btw.

Comment: I'm pretty sure even the second approach callls `find` under the hood. See https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#globalid also the Serializers section. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015598/activejob-globalid-and-in-memory-activerecord-objects . Personally I think the `find` in the job is unnecessary so I would prefer to use the Serializer system or just serialize the arguments to hash yourselff by some other means.

Comment: This also deals with an edge case where the record was deleted before the job ran

Comment: You gotta run numbers on this thing: benchmark and then optimise only the bottle necks. Nothing beats solid numbers.

Comment: If working with Sidekiq, pass always the values, not the whole object, [see](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-job-parameters-small-and-simple).

Comment: Option 2 implies that you already have the object on the caller's side. Why would you want to fetch the record again from the database? Unless of course you're implementing Sidekiq's `perform` method – that is supposed to take simple identifiers because of the de/serialization.